# Difference between predict(model) and predict(model$finalModel) using caret for classification in R

Tags: r, classification, prediction, r-caret

Whats the difference between

```
predict(rf, newdata=testSet)
```

and

```
predict(rf$finalModel, newdata=testSet)
```

i train the model with `preProcess=c("center", "scale")`

```
tc <- trainControl("repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=10, classProbs=TRUE, savePred=T)
rf <- train(y~., data=trainingSet, method="rf", trControl=tc, preProc=c("center", "scale"))
```

and i receive 0 true positives when i run it on a centered and scaled testSet

```
testSetCS <- testSet
xTrans <- preProcess(testSetCS)
testSetCS<- predict(xTrans, testSet)
testSet$Prediction <- predict(rf, newdata=testSet)
testSetCS$Prediction <- predict(rf, newdata=testSetCS)
```

but receive some true positives when i run it on an unscaled testSet.
I have to use the rf$finalModel to receive some true postives on the centered and scaled testSet and the rf object on the unscaled...what am i missing?

---

edit

tests:

```
tc <- trainControl("repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=10, classProbs=TRUE, savePred=T)
RF <-  train(Y~., data= trainingSet, method="rf", trControl=tc) #normal trainingData
RF.CS <- train(Y~., data= trainingSet, method="rf", trControl=tc, preProc=c("center", "scale")) #scaled and centered trainingData
```

on normal testSet:

```
RF predicts reasonable              (Sensitivity= 0.33, Specificity=0.97)
RF$finalModel predicts bad       (Sensitivity= 0.74, Specificity=0.36)
RF.CS predicts reasonable           (Sensitivity= 0.31, Specificity=0.97)
RF.CS$finalModel same results like RF.CS    (Sensitivity= 0.31, Specificity=0.97)
```

on centered and scaled testSetCS:

```
RF predicts very bad                (Sensitivity= 0.00, Specificity=1.00)
RF$finalModel predicts reasonable       (Sensitivity= 0.33, Specificity=0.98)
RF.CS predicts like RF              (Sensitivity= 0.00, Specificity=1.00)
RF.CS$finalModel predicts like RF       (Sensitivity= 0.00, Specificity=1.00)
```

so it seems as if the $finalModel needs the same format of trainingSet and testSet whereas the trained object accepts only uncentered and unscaled data, regardless of the selected preProcess parameter?

prediction code (where testSet is normal data and testSetCS is centered and scaled ):

```
testSet$Prediction <- predict(RF, newdata=testSet)
testSet$PredictionFM <- predict(RF$finalModel, newdata=testSet)
testSet$PredictionCS <- predict(RF.CS, newdata=testSet)
testSet$PredictionCSFM <- predict(RF.CS$finalModel, newdata=testSet)

testSetCS$Prediction <- predict(RF, newdata=testSetCS)
testSetCS$PredictionFM <- predict(RF$finalModel, newdata=testSetCS)
testSetCS$PredictionCS <- predict(RF.CS, newdata=testSetCS)
testSetCS$PredictionCSFM <- predict(RF.CS$finalModel, newdata=testSetCS)
```

Comment: can you please post the prediction code for your last train objects, i.e., RF, RF.CS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Frank,

This is really similar to your other question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/issue-on-prediction-with-finalmodel-of-randomforest-in-r-using-the-caret-package/81667#81667).

You really need to

1) show your exact prediction code for each result

2) give us a reproducible example.

With the normal `testSet`, `RF.CS` and `RF.CS$finalModel` should not be giving you the same results and we should be able to reproduce that. Plus, there are syntax errors in your code so it can't be exactly what you executed.

Finally, I'm not really sure why you would use the `finalModel` object at all. The point of `train` is to handle the details and doing things this way (which is your option) circumvents the complete set of code that would normally be applied.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
 library(mlbench)
 data(Sonar)

 set.seed(1)
 inTrain <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class)
 training <- Sonar[inTrain[[1]], ]
 testing <- Sonar[-inTrain[[1]], ]

 pp <- preProcess(training[,-ncol(Sonar)])
 training2 <- predict(pp, training[,-ncol(Sonar)])
 training2$Class <- training$Class
 testing2 <- predict(pp, testing[,-ncol(Sonar)])
 testing2$Class <- testing2$Class

 tc <- trainControl("repeatedcv", 
                    number=10, 
                    repeats=10, 
                    classProbs=TRUE, 
                    savePred=T)
 set.seed(2)
 RF <-  train(Class~., data= training, 
              method="rf", 
              trControl=tc)
 #normal trainingData
 set.seed(2)
 RF.CS <- train(Class~., data= training, 
                method="rf", 
                trControl=tc, 
                preProc=c("center", "scale")) 
 #scaled and centered trainingData
```

Here are some results:

```
 > ## These should not be the same
 > all.equal(predict(RF, testing,  type = "prob")[,1],
 +           predict(RF, testing2, type = "prob")[,1])
 [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.4067554"
 > 
 > ## Nor should these
 > all.equal(predict(RF.CS, testing,  type = "prob")[,1],
 +           predict(RF.CS, testing2, type = "prob")[,1])
 [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.3924037"
 > 
 > all.equal(predict(RF.CS,            testing, type = "prob")[,1],
 +           predict(RF.CS$finalModel, testing, type = "prob")[,1])
 [1] "names for current but not for target"
 [2] "Mean relative difference: 0.7452435" 
 >
 > ## These should be and are close (just based on the 
 > ## random sampling used in the final RF fits)
 > all.equal(predict(RF,    testing, type = "prob")[,1],
 +           predict(RF.CS, testing, type = "prob")[,1])
 [1] "Mean relative difference: 0.04198887"
```

Max

Comment: i used the $finalModel object because i thought that it contains the final (best) tree and therefore could calculate predictions and probabilities for new datasets.

Comment: It does and that is what `predict.train` uses. However, it might do some things to the data in-between that matter.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify the differences between `testing` and `testing2` due to `preProcess` as well as that the invocation on `predict.train` does uses `preProcess` internally while `predict(xx$finalModel)` does not. Otherwise the post reads a bit "voodoo-stuff-happens" as the role of `preProcess` is never clarified. (Obvious +1 though.)

Comment: Shouldn't the last example compare `RF` + `testing2` vs `RF.CS` + `testing`?