# Prediction of single bagged tree models dependent on pre-processing using caret

Tags: r, tree, r-caret

I'm using the `caret` package to predict a time series with method `treebag`. `caret` estimates bagging regression trees with 25 bootstrap replications.

What I'm struggling to understand is how the final prediction of that 'treebag model' relates to the predictions made by each of the 25 trees, depending on whether I use `caret::preProcess`, or not.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096909/difference-between-predictmodel-and-predictmodelfinalmodel-using-caret-for]) and the linked resources therein. (But could not draw the right conclusions from it.)

Here is an example using  the `economics` data. Let's say I want to predict `unemploy_rate`, which has to be created first.

```
# packages
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

# data
data("economics")

economics$unemploy_rate <- economics$unemploy / economics$pop * 100
x <- economics[, -c(1, 7)]
y <- economics[["unemploy_rate"]]
```

I wrote a function that extracts the 25 individual trees from the `train` object, makes a prediction for each tree, averages these 25 predictions, and compares this average with the prediction from the `train` object. It returns a plot.

```
predict_from_treebag <- function(model) {
  # extract 25 trees from train object
  bagged_trees <- map(.x = model$finalModel$mtrees, .f = pluck, "btree")

  # make a prediction for each tree
  pred_trees <- map(bagged_trees, .f = predict, newdata = x)
  names(pred_trees) <- paste0("tree_", seq_along(pred_trees))

  # aggreagte predictions
  pred_trees <- as.data.frame(pred_trees) %>%
    add_column(date = economics$date, .before = 1) %>%
    gather(tree, value, matches("^tree")) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(mean_pred_from_trees = mean(value)) %>%
    ungroup()

  # add prediction from train object
  pred_trees$bagging_model_prediction = predict(model, x)
  pred_trees <- pred_trees %>%
    gather(model, pred_value, 4:5)

  # plot
  p <- ggplot(data = pred_trees, aes(date)) +
        geom_line(aes(y = value, group = tree), alpha = .2) +
        geom_line(aes(y = pred_value, col = model)) +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         legend.position = "bottom"
        )

  p

}
```

Now I estimate two models, the first will be unscaled, the second will be centered and scaled.

```
preproc_opts <- list(unscaled = NULL,
                     scaled = c("center", "scale"))

# estimate the models
models <- map(preproc_opts, function(preproc)
    train(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    trControl = trainControl(method = "none"), # since there are no tuning parameters for this model
    metric = "RMSE",
    method = "treebag",
    preProcess = preproc
))

# apply predict_from_treebag to each model
imap(.x = models,
     .f = ~{predict_from_treebag(.x) + labs(title = .y)})
```

The results are shown below. The unscaled model prediction is the average of the 25 trees but why is each prediction from the 25 trees a constant when I use `preProcess`?

Thank you for any advice where I might be wrong.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
pred_trees <- map(bagged_trees, .f = predict, newdata = x)
```

in the function `predict_from_treebag`

this `predict` function is in fact `predict.rpart` since

```
class(bagged_trees[[1]])
```

`predict.rpart` does not know that you pre-processed the data in caret.

Here is a quick fix:

```
predict_from_treebag <- function(model) {
  # extract 25 trees from train object
  bagged_trees <- map(.x = model$finalModel$mtrees, .f = pluck, "btree")
  x <- economics[, -c(1, 7)]
  # make a prediction for each tree

  newdata = if(is.null(model$preProcess)) x else predict(model$preProcess, x)
  pred_trees <- map(bagged_trees, .f = predict, newdata = newdata)
  names(pred_trees) <- paste0("tree_", seq_along(pred_trees))

  # aggreagte predictions
  pred_trees <- as.data.frame(pred_trees) %>%
    add_column(date = economics$date, .before = 1) %>%
    gather(tree, value, matches("^tree")) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(mean_pred_from_trees = mean(value)) %>%
    ungroup()

  # add prediction from train object
  pred_trees$bagging_model_prediction = predict(model, x)
  pred_trees <- pred_trees %>%
    gather(model, pred_value, 4:5)

  # plot
  p <- ggplot(data = pred_trees, aes(date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = value, group = tree), alpha = .2) +
    geom_line(aes(y = pred_value, col = model)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "bottom"
    )

  p
}
```

Now after running:

```
preproc_opts <- list(unscaled = NULL,
                     scaled = c("center", "scale"))

models <- map(preproc_opts, function(preproc)
  train(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    trControl = trainControl(method = "none"), # since there are no tuning parameters for this model
    metric = "RMSE",
    method = "treebag",
    preProcess = preproc
  ))

map2(.x = models,
     .y = names(models),
     .f = ~{predict_from_treebag(.x) + labs(title = .y)})
```

the result is in line with the expected

[image]
[image]

Comment: @markus Glad to help. I added an updated `predict_from_treebag` function that will work on any `preProcess` called within train.